# Solve $\frac{11}{x(x-5)}+\frac6{x(x+4)}-\frac3{(x-4)(x-5)}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve this equation? I've tried adding it by taking LCM. I dont know what I'm doing wrong.
$$\frac{11}{x(x-5)}+\frac6{x(x+4)}-\frac3{(x-4)(x-5)}=0$$

Comment: Hint : The degree four polynomial in the denominator vanishes after you multiply both sides with that polynomial (why?) Thus leaving you with a quadratic equation to solve.

Answer (score 3):

First, whenever you solve an equation, you should find the domain.

$$x\neq0,5,4,-4$$

Taking LCM,

$$11(x+4)(x-4)+6(x-5)(x-4)-3x(x+4)=0$$

$$14x^2-66x-56=0$$

So the solutions are

$$x = \frac{33}{14} - \frac{\sqrt{1873}}{14}\approx5.448440715$$
$$x = \frac{33}{14} + \frac{\sqrt{1873}}{14}\approx-0.7341550012$$